# Imges not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

On my site when the user uploads their profile picture, it gets funny when the image dimentions are small. Below is an example

[image]

I dont know what to do is there a way to make my image come up properly when the image file is not with large dimensions.

Comment: can you post relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the container of the images has the width and height not the image and on the image use the following

```
object-fit:cover; 
object-position:center; 
width:100%; 
height:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this......

```
 img{
   display: block;
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="hair_care">
                <img src="/Content/BusinessProfileImages/bbef41d2.jpg">
        </div>
```

this is my code below of the css. That diesnt work for small images large files with large dimentions come good. and small files images look funny.

```
.hair_care {
    float: left;
    width: 318px;
}
```

Comment: try setting IMG max-width to 100% with CSS to retain original dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if there is width attribute on IMG tag or hard coded pixel/percentage width applied on image tag via CSS rule.

In case of width attribute with IMG tag, please remove that width tag and let CSS control the width and make sure that you set the 'max-width: 100%' and 'width: auto' which is the thumb rule for responsive design.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Second, if image is appearing as background image then check the "background-size" properties.